# Getting error like Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String] in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on express API and I am facing following issue.

```
    /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/routes/v1/blog.route.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/routes/v1/index.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/app.js:13:16)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here is my controller inside controllers folder
blog.controller.js

```
    const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');


const createBlog = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const blog = await blogService.createBlog(req.body);
    res.status(httpStatus.CREATED).send(blog);
  });


  module.exports = {
    createBlog
  };
```

here is blog.service.js inside services folder

```
    const { Blog } = require('../models');

/**
 * Create a blog
 * @param {Object} blogBody
 * @returns {Promise<Blog>}
 */
 const createBlog = async (blogBody) => {
    return Blog.create(blogBody);
  };


  module.exports = {
    createBlog
  };
```

here is index.js inside services folder

```
    module.exports.authService = require('./auth.service');
module.exports.emailService = require('./email.service');
module.exports.tokenService = require('./token.service');
module.exports.userService = require('./user.service');
module.exports.blogService = require('./blog.service');
```

here is blog.route.js inside routes/v1 folder

```
    const express = require('express');
const blogController = require('../../controllers/blog.controller');

const router = express.Router();

router
   .route('/')
   .post('manageBlogs', blogController.createBlog)


module.exports = router;
```

this is index.js inside routes/v1 folder

```
    const express = require('express');
const blogRoute = require('./blog.route');
const authRoute = require('./auth.route');
const userRoute = require('./user.route');
const docsRoute = require('./docs.route');
const config = require('../../config/config');

const router = express.Router();

const defaultRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/auth',
    route: authRoute,
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    route: userRoute,
  },
  {
    path: '/blogs',
    route: blogRoute,
  }
];

const devRoutes = [
  // routes available only in development mode
  {
    path: '/docs',
    route: docsRoute,
  },
];

defaultRoutes.forEach((route) => {
  router.use(route.path, route.route);
});


if (config.env === 'development') {
  devRoutes.forEach((route) => {
    router.use(route.path, route.route);
  });
}

module.exports = router;
```

this is my model blog.model.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { toJSON, paginate } = require('./plugins');
const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    shortdescription: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    author: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    image: { type: String },
    country: [{
      name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
      },
      countryid: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true
      },
      isocode: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
      }  
      }],
    city: [{
      name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
      },
      cityid: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true
      }
      }],
    category: [{
      name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
      },
      catid: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true
      }
    }],
    seo: {
      metatitle: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
       trim: true,
      },
      metadesc: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
      },
      metakeywords: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
      }
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// add plugin that converts mongoose to json
blogSchema.plugin(toJSON);
blogSchema.plugin(paginate);


/**
 * @typedef Blog
 */
const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);

module.exports = Blog;
```

when I remove **.post('manageBlogs', blogController.createBlog)** from blog.routes.js, it starts working.

Comment: The err is at yow catchAsync, but if you don't show it I cannot tell you why

Comment: return res.status(httpStatus.CREATED).send(blog); it will solve the problem

Comment: @Senthil - I tried but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look after reading yow stack trace I found out the reason of this err. I wont tell you the answer, instead I show you how to find them errs by your own.

the error

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String]
```

the first line of the stack trace says

```
  at Route.<computed> [as post] (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
```

it talks about something from `node_modules` so we dont care

next line

```
 at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/routes/v1/blog.route.js:8:5)
```

look this one is not from `node_modules`, this is `/src/routes/v1/blog.route.js:8:5` ours

```
/src/routes/v1/blog.route.js:8:5
```

8 means line 8 5 means fif character. so lets count

the 8th line is this one

```
 .post('manageBlogs', blogController.createBlog)
```

the error says **Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String]**

if we go to express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

we can find and example

```
app.route('/book')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book')
  })
```

now compare the one you have

```
router
   .route('/')
   .post('manageBlogs', blogController.createBlog)
```

with the one gave it by express

```
app.route('/book')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book')
  })
```

Comment: thanks for the hint ! I solved it by replacing .post('manageBlogs', blogController.createBlog) with router.post('/manageBlogs', blogController.createBlog);